# How to insert data from a list to SQLite3 Database

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a list below imported the data from qwidgets.

```
list = ['2020/02/21', 'name', 'location', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']
```

or

```
list = ['2020/02/21', 'name', 'location', 'item1']
```

or

```
list = ['2020/02/21', 'name', 'location', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

How to insert this list data in to SQLite3 database. I am using below database structure.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
conn.execute("INSERT INTO \
    maintable(date,name,location,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6, item7,item8, item9, item10) \
    VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')
```

Comment: Please read the docs of the sqlite API, you need a cursor from the connection, then you should fill the lists with empty items, so it has the same length on every insert. Then you need to access the list items on insert (with list[0], list[1] etc.). Also never name a variable `list` in python, because that will shadow the built-in function `list()`. Use `my_list`or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never build a request by adding parameter values into the query string. I used to be the vector for the old *SQL injection* attack that allowed an attacker to pass arbitrary SQL commands by simply *forging* a parameter value.

The recommended way is to used a parameterized query.

Here you should simply do:

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO \
    maintable(date,name,location,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6, item7,item8, item9, item10) \
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", lst + [None] * (13 - len(lst)))
```

BTW I renamed your list variable `lst` to avoid hiding the built-in `list` function.

Comment: I used the code but getting the error like this. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Oops... There was a typo in my code: the closing `]` was misplaced. Fixed.

Comment: I updated your code. Now TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'list'

Comment: There was a second typo: I renamed `list` to `lst` at only one place...

Answer (score 2):

It's better and safer to use placeholders (?) wherever you want to use a value to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Since the size of the list can vary you need to build it dynamically. You can do that like this:

```
l = ['2020/02/21', 'name', 'location', 'item1', 'item2',...]
query = "INSERT INTO maintable(date,name,location"

for i in range(len(l) - 3):
    query += ',item{}'.format(i+1)

query += ") VALUES (?, ?, ?"

for i in range(len(l) - 3):
    query += ', ?'.format(i+1)
query += ')'

conn.execute(query, l)
```

Make sure you supply all the values for the placeholders and remember to commit and close the connection to save the changes:

```
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Showing the error: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 13, and there are 5 supplied.

Comment: @user3030327 I don't think you have supplied all the parameter values. There should be 10 item values in the list after date, name and location. The number of ? and values have to match exactly.

Comment: If the list has 13 items  the code is  working. But i need some times the list has less than 13 items. so the error is coming.

Comment: @user3030327 So if the list has less than 13 items then do you want to leave it blank?

Comment: Yes. I want to leave them blank.

Comment: @user3030327 Try my updated answer. You have to build the query string dynamically depending on the size of the list.

Comment: Its also Working.

Comment: @user3030327 Good to hear that. Initially I didn't realise you were not writing to all item columns. I also like Serge Ballesta's answer.